# Vim regex match a space, a number and everything else until ;

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to make this regex but it's driving me insane. I've strings like this:

```
foobar 34;lorem ipsum;
foo 34/ABC;dolerm sit;
bar 3445b;amet;
```

I need to transform them like this:

```
foobar;34;lorem ipsum;
foo;34/ABC;dolerm sit;
bar;3445b;amet;
```

The regex I come up to is this one but it matches only numbers: `\s\d*;` and this one matches the whole line `\s\d*\p*;`
I need something to match only a white space, a number and than everything until the first ";".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

does this work for you?

```
%s/ \ze\d/;/g
```

if you want to change

```
foo bar 3 r e p l a c e;bar;
```

to

```
foo bar;3;r;e;p;l;a;c;e;bar;

%s/ \d[^;]*/\=substitute(submatch(0)," ",";","g")/
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably could get your original patterns working, if you used "non-greedy" matches, for example `\p\{-}` for "any number of printable characters, but as few as possible", or by explicitly excluding the ';' character with `[^;]*` (any number of any character that is not a ';').

`:help non-greedy`
`:help /[` (then scroll down below the E769 topic)